# Android Spinner get position of string in code behind

Tags: android, spinner

i have a spinner which i catch onClick like that:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        position = pos;
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }
```

I want to check if String for example `String example = "example"` is in the Spinner ItemList and get its position, Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to know if the user selected `"example"` or if `"example"` is somewhere in the list?

Comment: i want to check WHERE exacly "example" is on the list

Comment: Ok, you should find the position of `"example"` in once your `onCreate()` method, not every time an item is selected. But _how_ you do this depends on the adapter. What type of adapter are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with

```
 spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

you can get the Text which is currently selected. 
with

```
spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

you can get the current position.
You can compare the selected String like this:

```
if(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("example")){
//do something
};
```

Comment: User asked to check given string position in Spinner.this only check if current value is equal to given string

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
    if (mSpinner.getItemAtPosition(i).equals(MY_STRING)) {
        mSpinner.setSelection(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

if you wish to set an item on spinner init `onNothingSelected` won't help you here since this callback is called only when selected item is removed from the list of available items.

> Callback method to be invoked when the selection disappears from this
> view. The selection can disappear for instance when touch is activated
> or when the adapter becomes empty.

[docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html#onNothingSelected%28android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E%29)